# trying to add Flags to Currency Converter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[www.womenpalace.com](http://www.womenpalace.com)

hello :)

i'm trying to add Flags images next to my Currency Converter.

this is the converter code:

```html
<select id ="currencies" class="currencies" name="currencies" data-default-shop-currency="{{ shop.currency }}" onchange="onFlagChange(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"> 
  {% capture codes %},USD,EUR,GBP,CAD,ARS,AUD,ILS,BBD,BDT,BSD,BHD,BRL,BOB,BND,BGN,MMK,KYD,CLP,CNY,COP,CRC,HRK,CZK,DKK,DOP,XCD,EGP,XPF,FJD,GHS,GTQ,GYD,GEL,HKD,HUF,ISK,INR,IDR,NIS,JMD,JPY,JOD,KZT,KES,KWD,LVL,LTL,MXN,MYR,MUR,MDL,MAD,MNT,MZN,ANG,NZD,NGN,NOK,OMR,PKR,PYG,PEN,PHP,PLN,QAR,RON,RUB,SAR,RSD,SCR,SGD,SYP,ZAR,KRW,LKR,SEK,CHF,TWD,THB,TZS,TTD,TRY,UAH,AED,UYU,VEB,VND,ZMK,{% endcapture %}
  {% assign supported_codes = settings.supported_currencies | split: ' ' %}
  <option value="{{ shop.currency }}" selected="selected">{{ shop.currency }}</option>
  {% for code in supported_codes %}
    {% if code != shop.currency and codes contains code %}
    <option value="{{ code }}">{{ code }}</option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

i made some JavaScript code to force the IMG to chenge when i select different currency

```js
function onFlagChange(userSelection){
        var newUrl;
        var optionUrl =
                [
{key:"USD",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/USD.png?13296612461826194053"},
{key:"GBP",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/GBP.png?11949257934149418133"},
{key:"EUR",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/EUR.png?11949257934149418133"},
{key:"ILS",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/ILS.png?11949257934149418133"},
{key:"RUB",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/RUB.png?11949257934149418133"}
                ]
        var pick = optionUrl.find(function(e) { return e.key === userSelection; });
        if (pick) {
                newUrl = pick.value;
        }
        $('#flags').attr('src',newUrl);
    }
```

and this is the IMG that should change when i select different currency

```html
<span>
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/{{ shop.currency }}.png" id="flags" >
</span>
```

everything work fine, **BUT** when i refresh/browse to another page, the IMG change to the USD flag. even if i choose GBP for example.

Any Suggestion How i make the flag to preview the selected currency even if i refresh or browse to another page?

this is the entire system:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/services/javascripts/currencies.js" data-no-instant></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ "jquery.currencies.min.js" | asset_url }}" data-no-instant></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  {% if settings.currency_format %}
    Currency.format = '{{ settings.currency_format }}';
  {% endif %}

  var shopCurrency = '{{ shop.currency }}';

  /* Sometimes merchants change their shop currency, let's tell our JavaScript file */
  Currency.money_with_currency_format[shopCurrency] = {{ shop.money_with_currency_format | strip_html | json }};
  Currency.money_format[shopCurrency] = {{ shop.money_format | strip_html | json }};

  /* Default currency */
  var defaultCurrency = '{{ settings.default_currency }}' || shopCurrency;
  
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
    var $currencySelector = $(".top_bar .currencies");
  } else {
    var $currencySelector = $("#mobile_menu .currencies");
  }
  
  /* Cookie currency */
  var cookieCurrency = Currency.cookie.read();

  /* Fix for customer account pages */
  $('span.money span.money').each(function() {
    $(this).parents('span.money').removeClass('money');
  });

  /* Saving the current price */
  $('span.money').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-currency-{{ shop.currency }}', $(this).html());
  });
    
    
  // If there's no cookie.
  if (cookieCurrency == null) {
    if (shopCurrency !== defaultCurrency) {
      Currency.convertAll(shopCurrency, defaultCurrency);
    }
    else {
      Currency.currentCurrency = defaultCurrency;
    }
  }
  // If the cookie value does not correspond to any value in the currency dropdown.
  else if ($currencySelector.length && $currencySelector.find('option[value=' + cookieCurrency + ']').length === 0) {
    Currency.currentCurrency = shopCurrency;
    Currency.cookie.write(shopCurrency);
  }
  else if (cookieCurrency === shopCurrency) {
    Currency.currentCurrency = shopCurrency;
  }
  else {
    Currency.convertAll(shopCurrency, cookieCurrency);
  }

  $currencySelector.val(Currency.currentCurrency).change(function() {
    var newCurrency = $(this).val();
    Currency.convertAll(Currency.currentCurrency, newCurrency);
    jQuery('.selected-currency').text(Currency.currentCurrency);
  });

  var original_selectCallback = window.selectCallback;
  var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
    original_selectCallback(variant, selector);
    Currency.convertAll(shopCurrency, $currencySelector.val());
    jQuery('.selected-currency').text(Currency.currentCurrency);
  };

  function convertCurrencies() {
    if($currencySelector.val() && $currencySelector.val() != $currencySelector.data('default-shop-currency')) {
      Currency.convertAll($currencySelector.data('default-shop-currency'), $currencySelector.val());
      jQuery('.selected-currency').text(Currency.currentCurrency);
    }
  }
   
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Use local storage or db?

Comment: it's Shopify platform

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by 302 redirecting to a new currency-specific URL. But you would probably be happier setting a cookie, and then choosing the current currency based on that cookie.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. yes it's probably work on cookie. can you help me please to make it work? :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps call onFlagChange($currencySelector.val()) at the end of function convertCurrencies - the currency changes after the page loads, so it starts with a different img src.  Possibly the .change() is not triggering the onchange listener.

Please pardon any goofy formatting, typing on a tablet is special...

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not the cleanest approach, but the reason it is not working on a page change is because the event only fires after a selection is made. Also the src url is not persistent. You need an event that fires on load as well.

```js
function onFlagChange(userSelection){
        var newUrl;
        if(!userSelection) { // NEW CODE
          userSelection = $('#currencies').find(":selected").text();
        }
        var optionUrl =
                [
{key:"USD",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/USD.png?13296612461826194053"},
{key:"GBP",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/GBP.png?11949257934149418133"},
{key:"EUR",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/EUR.png?11949257934149418133"},
{key:"ILS",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/ILS.png?11949257934149418133"},
{key:"RUB",value:"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2078/5043/t/59/assets/RUB.png?11949257934149418133"}
                ]
        var pick = optionUrl.find(function(e) { return e.key === userSelection; });
        if (pick) {
                newUrl = pick.value;
        }
        $('#flags').attr('src',newUrl);
    }
```

Then either add a jQuery onLoad event or put it in the DOM on the body or select like this

```
<select id="currencies" onload="onFlagChange(false)">
```

Comment: thank you. i didn't understand the JQuery part. can you explain better?

Comment: you can do $("#currencies").load(function() {}) in the outer scope of your script to have some stuff happen when the element loads.

Comment: i replace my Java to yours and place the $("#currencies").load(function() {}) after the $('#flags').attr('src',newUrl); line. not working :(

Comment: you've gotta put stuff in there  $("#currencies").load(function() { onFlagChange(false) });

Comment: also you need to put that line outside of that function

Comment: i put the line $("#currencies").load(function() { onFlagChange(false) }); outside the function..still now working my friend